# Dynamic svelte:element with both self-closing and non-self-closing variants

Tags: svelte

Given the following code, where `node.tag` can be either `input` or `button`:

```html
  {#each nodes as node}
    <svelte:element
      this={node.tag}
      type={node.type}
      name={node.name}
    >
      {#if node.tag === 'button'}
        {node.label}
      {/if}
    </svelte:element>
  {/each}
```

I get the following warning in the console when `node.tag` is `input`:

```
<svelte:element this="input"> is self-closing and cannot have content
```

Is there any way to avoid this warning? I would like to be able to dynamically render both self-closing and non-self-closing elements in a loop and only ultimately have children when such a thing would be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have two options, do you really need `svelte:element`?

```html
{#each nodes as node}
  {@const { tag, ...rest } = node}
  {#if node.tag == 'button'}
    <button {...rest} >{node.label}</button>
  {:else}
    <input {...rest} />
  {/if}
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c2102962df824a1db55fe765faa942e6?version=3.52.0)

Comment: There are many more options, I reduced it to two to make the question simpler to grok.

Comment: Though that `@const` syntax is new to me and rather interesting! I'll give it a try.

Comment: That was an oversimplification that should have been pointed out. If you have more options you should still be able to use this approach to single out elements that have content.

Comment: That syntax wound up working for my scenario. Thank you!